# Разные версия типа в схожих пространствах

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

При попытки использовать пространство имен System.Collections.ObjectModel выдает ошибку разных версий

> Ошибка    CS0433  Тип "ObservableCollection" существует как в "System.Windows, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e", так и в "System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".    ASAM Administrator  F:\Microsoft Visual Studio 2012\ASAM\ASAM\RDP_Client\VideoSettings.cs   112 Активно

как указать однозначность версии, свойство Embed Interop Type не помогает.

Answer (score 1):

*Точно не знаю, но очень похоже что дело вот в чем.*

Библиотека `System.Windows` пятой версии не может работать с 4м фреймворком. Поставьте в настройках проекта самую последнюю версию фреймворка - или перейдите на `System.Windows` версии 4.0.0.0

Comment: он всеравно пишет эту ошибку